# C programming, segmentation fault when manipulating strings

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, segmentation-fault

I have an array of strings defined as an array of pointers to string as following

```
char* dict[50];
dict[0][0]= 0;
printf("%d", dict[0][0]);
```

// This gives a segmentation fault, could someone please explain why so? Also if I put dict[0]=0, is it the same as dict[0][0]=0

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you haven't allocated any memory. `char* dict[50]` is a 50 elements long array of char pointers: if these pointers haven't been pointed to valid memory, writing to them is undefined behaviour and will frequently crash your program or worse.

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of 50 pointers, none of which is initialised.

Executing `dict[0]=0` sets the first array element to the `NULL` pointer.

Executing `dict[0][0]=0` dereferences an uninitialised pointer, or, if you have already done `dict[0]=0`, dereferences a `NULL` pointer.